# Cannot access adb shell on emulated x86 phone

Tags: adb, android-emulator

Trying to get access to a phone on Android emulator via adb. Error message returned:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb shell error: device unauthorized.
This adb server's $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS is not set
Try 'adb kill-server' if that seems wrong.
Otherwise check for a confirmation dialog on your device.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>
```

I have deleted the adbkey and adbkey.pub files from the .android folder as suggested in some question/answers for physical phones without success. Also disabling and re-enabling USB debugging on the phone.

Phone details:
Device - Nexus 7 (7.02", 1200 x 1920: xhdpi)
Target - Android 8.0.0 - API Level 26
CPU/ABI- Google Play Intel Atom (x86)

Any ideas on how to get adb access? Thanks.

Comment: Same problem here. I tried to use different system image  - `Google APIs` instead of `Google Play`, but it does not even boot due to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/66114788 .

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with an x86 emulator sdk 24

1. Settings -> About emulated device -> click on "Build number" several times (as you do on a real device)
2. go to Settings -> Developer options -> turn on "USB debugging"

you should be getting a dialog to enable debugging access from the pc

and attempt running again via Android Studio